# How to write Teardown for RowEntryFixture or ColumnFixture in Fitnesse

Tags: fitnesse, fixture, teardown

I am using `RowEntryFixture` to process some data, at the end of it, I want to execute some code, how can i do that?
I am using fitnesse with C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override DoTable:

```
public override void DoTable(Parse table) {
    DoRows(table.Parts.More);
    DoSomeStuffAtEnd();
}
```